# add & delete row in table usin jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how  to add rows in table in html using jquery through popup.
In Popup we have text fields,checkbox and radio button and add button. 
when I will click on add button then row add in table.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share.

Comment: @BeingSunny I want to add row in table using popup

Comment: @SimonH I just add rows in table through popup or dialog using jquery

Comment: Happy to provide help once you have at least attempted to solve this yourself.

Comment: @SimonH I have tried But I am facing a problem to add row in table through popup

Comment: Ok, as I asked before, can you please share some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery datatables which allows you to do that , Check this example :

[Adding new row jQuery datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)

You can use Bootstrap modals [Boostrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) | build a form in it with custom submit function that exists in the first link.